# How to add a new set of data to this code using a method

Tags: java, arraylist

Im trying to add a new method called "add" and am not sure on how to go about it. The method has to add a new data set for a new monster. Im not sure if i need to change my data into an arraylist<> nor am i sure of how to do that to begin with. If possible id prefer a way to add to existing data without creating an arraylist

```
package monstertester;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MonsterTester {


   public static int listMonster()
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Which monster would you like to see? ");
      System.out.println("1) Ogre");
      System.out.println("2) Vampire");
      System.out.println("3) Werewolf");
      System.out.println("4) Dinosaur");
      System.out.println("5) hexenbiest");

      int choice = in.nextInt();

      return choice;

   }

   public static void displayMonster(Monster whichMonster)
   {
      System.out.println("Monster Stats");
      System.out.println("Name: " + whichMonster.getName());
      System.out.println("Type: " + whichMonster.getType());
      System.out.println("Age: " + whichMonster.getAge());
      System.out.println("Health: " + whichMonster.getHealth());
      System.out.println("Favorite Weapon: " + whichMonster.getWeapon());
   }

   public static int menu()
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

      System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
      System.out.println("1) Display a monster");
      System.out.println("2) Celebrate a monster's birthday");
      System.out.println("3) Update a monster's health");
      System.out.println("4) Add a new monster") ;

      int choice = in.nextInt();

      return choice;

   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      //Variable declarations
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int choice = 0;
      String play = "y";



      Monster ogre = new Monster("Shrek", "ogre", 40, 90, "club");
      Monster vampire = new Monster("Dracula", "vampire", 460, 100, "fangs");
      Monster werewolf = new Monster("Jacob", "werewolf", 18, 75, "teeth");
      Monster experiment = new Monster("Stitch", "experiment", 200, 85, "claws");
      Monster hexenbiest = new Monster("Sean", "hexenbiest", 35, 85, "magic");
```

Comment: Create a list ```ArrayList<Monster>``` and add your ```Monster``` objects into the list inside your ```add()``` method.

Answer (score 0):

Well...you need to store each monster's data right..?, I can see that you already have some monster objects created, So I'm going to suggest like this...

you can create a method called addMonsters(); your method should include these things.

1. First create a [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) type of monster(because you want to store monster type objects.
2. Then you can store your moster type objects(which contains moster details) into the ArrayList you have created by using .add() method.

   ```
      monsters.add(ogre);
   ```

Comment: could you give an example of that? i think i understand but im not sure what that will look like.

Comment: I posted a new answer.. check it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    cars.add("Volvo");
    cars.add("BMW");
    cars.add("Ford");
    cars.add("Mazda");
    System.out.println(cars);
  }
}
```

Instead of String use Monster when you create the arraylist..you have to use your class name...which is monster, and you have to pass your objects which needs to added to the arraylist using add() method... I hope this helps you.

Comment: but how would you add stuff like the 'bmw' is 'red' & 'lowered', the 'ford' is 'blue' and 'lifted'

Comment: in this example, it only stores one string object, like that you can store the whole Monster object as a single instance using add() method.